# Append values from one dict to a dict of lists and append None where the keys don't match to keep lists the same length

Tags: python

I have two dicts.

```py
d1 = {
    "A": 10,
    "C": 30,
}
d2 = {
    "A": [1, 5],
    "B": [3, 6],
    "C": [90, 2],
    "D": [7, 22],
}
```

And I would like to add the values from `d1` to the lists in `d2`. Where the keys from `d1` are not in `d2`, then `None` is added to the lists at the missing keys in `d2`. So that all the lists remain the same length. For a result that looks like this:

```
merged = {
    "A": [1, 5, 10],
    "B": [3, 6, None],
    "C": [90, 2, 30],
    "D": [7, 22, None],
}
```

What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.get` method on `d1` to extract the value for a key or `None` if the key is missing

```py
for key in d2.keys():
    d2[key].append(d1.get(key))
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.keys()`, dictionaries already expose an iterator over their keys: `for key in d2:`

Comment: I know! I still think that beeing explicit is better though...

Answer (score 2):

```
d1 = {
    "A": 10,
    "C": 30,
}
d2 = {
    "A": [1, 5],
    "B": [3, 6],
    "C": [90, 2],
    "D": [7, 22],
}

merged = {k: v + [d1.get(k)] for k, v in d2.items()}

print(merged)
# {'A': [1, 5, 10], 'B': [3, 6, None], 'C': [90, 2, 30], 'D': [7, 22, None]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid modifying `d2`, you can create a new dictionary to store your output like so:

```py
merged = {}
for key, value in d2.items():
    merged[key] = value + [d1.get(key)]
```

Comment: I think using `append` is better than creating a list from a single element and using the `+` operator (talking about `value + [d1.get(key)]`)

Comment: I agree that `append` does look nice and clean, but `append` will modify the values in `d2` which is what I was trying to avoid. This could be instead written as `[*value, d1.get(key)]`

Comment: `value.copy().append(d1.get(key))` would work as well

Answer (score 0):

Define "efficient". There are two possible answers for the problem.

**The first** is to use a for loop, like this:

```
for key in d2.keys():
    d2[key].append(d1.get(key))
```

Explaining: you go through the keys of the bigger dict, then use get to verify if the key exists in d1 and append the value, or None, to d2. The output is d2.

**The second** solution would be to use pandas' DataFrames, which may be more efficient.
The process is simple, turn everything into a DataFrame, then just merge them.

At the top of your code, import the pandas package, or the DataFrame module.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```

Then, after defining your d1 and d2

```
df1 = DataFrame(d1, index=[0])
df2 = DataFrame(d2)
merged = df2.append(df1)
```

Explaining: as d1 doesn't contains a list, you need to determine that the only entry in the DataFrame is in index=0, the d2 don't need it, because the list already set their indexes;
the columns of the DataFrame will be the keys of the dictionary.

Later you can turn your DataFrame back to a dictionary, but this would render the method unefficient.